pcolormesh plotting problem: the exception reporting (erroneously?) incorrect sizes of input data arrays
I've faced the problem with making 2D plot. I use pcolormesh method, taken from some matplotlip->pyplot package class.
I attach the following code to give an overview of my datasets (put some prints to ensure that all types/sizes are OK)
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
-------->8-----------
nY = len(Y)
nX = len(X)

X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)
C = np.zeros((nX-1,nY-1))

print(f"C.shape = {C.shape}, C.type = {type(C)}")
print(f"X.shape = {X.shape}, X.type = {type(X)}")
print(f"Y.shape = {Y.shape}, Y.type = {type(Y)}")


for x in range(nX - 1):
    for y in range(nY - 1):
        C[x,y] = 1.  # fill 2D-array with any dummy floats

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, C)
-------->8-----------

Well, at the end of the day I got this exception with the explanation which seems be utterly senseless to me:
raise TypeError(f"Dimensions of C {C.shape} should" TypeError: Dimensions of C (15, 79) should be one smaller than X(16) and Y(80) while using shading='flat' see help(pcolormesh)
Relevant excerpt of the output is:
> C.shape = (15, 79), C.type = <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
> X.shape = (16,), X.type = <class 'numpy.ndarray'> 
> Y.shape = (80,), Y.type = <class 'numpy.ndarray'> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\some_dir\some_file.py", line 67, in <module>
>     ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, C)   File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py",
> line 1478, in inner
>     return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py",
> line 6289, in pcolormesh
>     X, Y, C, shading = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args,
>                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py",
> line 5836, in _pcolorargs
>     raise TypeError(f"Dimensions of C {C.shape} should" TypeError: Dimensions of C (15, 79) should be one smaller than X(16) and Y(80)
> while using shading='flat' see help(pcolormesh)
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1

What's going on? I appreciate any help

Well, meanwhile I found out that the problem could be caused by incorrect assignment of X, Y arrays to (x, y) variables in plot. I swapped them to:
ax.pcolormesh(Y, X, C)

and the problem is gone. Hope, that some day this will help somebody.
